# Currently creating a 'check-in' command for guild raiding

Tags: javascript, arrays, bots, discord.js

I am currently trying to create a 'check-in' bot command for guild raiding.

Simply put, whenever a user types `!checkin`, their username will be registered into the raid team. This will keep going until raid team becomes full. Here is my current code:

```
if (command === "checkin") {
  let team = [];
  team.push(message.member.displayName)
}
```

Right now this code only registers 1 user to the team, and I know it's because whenever the command is called, the array is set to an empty array. How would I rewrite this code to make it so that whenever a user types `!checkin`, they will be pushed into the array, and when the next person does it, he will be pushed into the updated array instead of the empty one?

Comment: Hi, I'm removing the `push` tag since it's meant for version control, not for `Array.push()` :)

Answer (score 2):

If I'm correct, your code would look something like this:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client()

client.on('message', msg => {
    // ... previous code
    if (command == 'checkin') {
        team.push(message.member.displayName);
    }
})
```

The issue is that the array '`team'` is not defined in the correct scope. You should define your array outside of the `client.on('message', msg => {` block like below:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client()
var team = [];
```

This will allow the array to be pushed into inside of the message function and still retain its original contents.

If you would like to read more on JavaScript variable scope, I found this webpage helped me out: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp